# Enzymatic mechanism of Lipase

Tags: organic-chemistry, enzymes, enzyme-kinetics

When lipase catalyses the *hydrolysis* of a triglyceride (oil/fat) which bond does it break and why?
What about in the case of saponification (triglyceride + NaOH) in the presence of lipase?
Is the same bond broken in both cases?

If during esterification, alcohol gives H and acid gives OH, then during hydrolysis/saponification is the
O—COR the bond broken by lipase?
[image]

Comment: As shown here https://proteopedia.org/wiki/index.php/Lipase  the O-COR bond is broken

Answer (score 1):

As an Organic chemistry/Biochemistry student, you must understand when bond making and bond breaking reaction occur *in vitro* or *in vivo* conditions, it's always involved the weakest bond. For example, weakest bond in a ester hydrolysis is bond between carbonyl carbon and oxygen attached to corresponding alkyl group $(\ce{R-C(=O)-OR'})$, which would break during the hydrolysis regardless of the conditions. Difference between ester hydrolysis by $\ce{NaOH}$  and lipases is no specificity when used $\ce{NaOH}$ (e.g., both 1,3- or 2-lincages in glyceride will be break to give glycerol and fatty acids as products), but could have high specificity when used lipases.

The ref.1 gives a general mechanism of hydrolysis by a lipase:

[image: Mechanism of lipase catalysis]

**Figure 1. Mechanism of lipase catalysis** (From Ref.1)

> Their (lipases') catalytic triad is composed of serine, histidine and aspartate or glutamate, which is also found in serine proteases. The mechanisms involved during lipase catalysis are illustrated in Fig. 1. In the first step, serine is activated by deprotonation, for which histidine and aspartate are required (Fig. 1a). Consequently, the nucleophilicity of the hydroxyl residue of serine is enhanced and attacks the carbonyl group of the substrate forming an acyl-enzyme intermediate (Fig. 1b). The presence of an oxianion hole contributes to the stabilization of charge distribution and reduction of the ground state energy of the tetrahedral intermediate. The deacylation step in Fig. 1c is shown which is controlled by the electronegativity of the molecules populating the interface. In this process a nucleophile (e.g. $\ce{H2O}$ or monoglyceride) attacks the acylated enzyme leading to product release and regeneration of the catalytic site.

**References:**

1. P. Reis, K. Holmberg, H. Watzke, M.E. Leser, and R. Miller, "Lipases at interfaces: A review," *Advances in Colloid and Interface Science* **2009**, *147–148*, 237-250 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cis.2008.06.001).